# JavaFX ScrollPane - speed up swiping effect on touch device

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

I found that if I swipe within a ScrollPane in a JavaFX application on a touch device, the scroll-animation is quite slow. I do not swipe over the ScrollBar of the ScrollPane but within the content itself.

How can I speed up the swipe animation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem with touch devices and the ScrollPane ;)
If you want to speedup the animation you have to set the position by your own.
I solved the same problem I while ago on this way, worked well.
You need to do something like this:

```
ScrollPane scrollPane = new ScrollPane();
    final IntegerProperty vValueProperty = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
    final int steps = 5;

    scrollPane.vvalueProperty().bind(vValueProperty);

    scrollPane.setOnSwipeDown(new EventHandler<GestureEvent>() {

        public void handle(GestureEvent event) {
            // calculate the needed value here
            vValueProperty.set(vValueProperty.get() + steps);
        }
    });
```

If the normal swipe animation disturbes you, just kill the event with

```
event.consume();
```

But it could be that you need to use an EventFilter in this case cause the EventFilter is called before the Event is doing anything. Can't remember if a consume() at the end of the EventHandler is enough. If not you need to use something like this:

```
scrollPane.addEventFilter(SwipeEvent.SWIPE_DOWN,
            new EventHandler<SwipeEvent>() {

                public void handle(SwipeEvent event) {

                    vValueProperty.set(vValueProperty.get() - steps);

                    event.consume();

                }
            });
```

Well this is just to speedup the animation. If you want your Pane following your finger, just save the first value, which you get OnTouchDetected and calculate the Offset OnTouchMoved. This is your value you can use to translate the Pane correctly. :)
Hope it is useful. I don't have a touch device here to test it.

Comment: i wasn't able to test this solution, but thank you for your answer. I hope it can help somebody.

Comment: I have a javafx touch application on a tablet, some screens require scroll.  I initially used ScrollPane, but the scroll experience was not smooth.  And when you swiped up/down, the screen only moved a little.  So, I instead used ListView instead of ScrollPane. The content is in VBox, and I put the VBox in the ListView.  The scrolling is now smooth and fast.